# ViewState won't hold dynamically created controls' value, even though I preserve the same ids in postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a simple form generating webpage that user can select different controls via a `DropDownList`, add a `Text` property to it(and a `GroupName` property if ii was a `RadioButton`) and then click a button to generate that control right in the page for previewing purpose (I am also going to add another button to insert the form's information in a database but this is not my problem right now)

this is my aspx page:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
<form dir="rtl" id="form" runat="server">
    <label>Desired Control : </label>
    <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlControlType" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlControlType_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="label"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="text box"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="check box"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="radio button"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    <label class="label">control's text : </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxText" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
    <label class="label">group name (only for radio button)</label>
    <asp:TextBox Enabled="false" ID="txtboxGroupName" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddControl" CssClass="btn" Text="add to form" OnClick="btnAddControl_Click" runat="server" />
    <hr />
    <h1>form preview</h1>
    <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

this is the code behind:

```
public Dictionary<string, Type> ControlTypes
{
    get { return (Dictionary<string, Type>)Session["ControlTypes"]; }
    set { Session["ControlTypes"] = value; }
}
public int NumberOfControls
{
    get { return (int)ViewState["NumOfControls"]; }
    set { ViewState["NumOfControls"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.NumberOfControls = 0;
        ControlTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    }
    else
        this.CreateControls();
}

private void CreateControls()
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < this.NumberOfControls; counter++)
    {
        string controlId = "control_id_" + counter.ToString();
        Type controlType = ControlTypes[controlId];
        PropertyInfo[] properties = controlType.GetProperties();
        object controlObject = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Name == "ID")
                property.SetValue(controlObject, controlId, null);
        }
        panel.Controls.Add(controlObject as Control);
    }
}

protected void ddlControlType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (ddlControlType.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        case 2:
            txtboxText.Enabled = true;
            txtboxGroupName.Enabled = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            txtboxText.Enabled = false;
            txtboxGroupName.Enabled = false;
            break;
        case 3:
            txtboxText.Enabled = true;
            txtboxGroupName.Enabled = true;
            break;
    }
}

protected void btnAddControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control tempControl = null;
    switch (ddlControlType.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            tempControl = new Label();
            ((Label)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
            break;
        case 1:
            tempControl = new TextBox();
            break;
        case 2:
            tempControl = new CheckBox();
            ((CheckBox)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
            break;
        case 3:
            tempControl = new RadioButton();
            ((RadioButton)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
            ((RadioButton)tempControl).GroupName = txtboxGroupName.Text;
            break;
    }
    string controlId = "control_id_" + this.NumberOfControls.ToString();
    tempControl.ID = controlId;
    panel.Controls.Add(tempControl);
    this.NumberOfControls++;
    ControlTypes.Add(controlId, tempControl.GetType());
}
```

as you can see, I preserve the id's of the controls, but the viewstate won't update their values.the controls will be added to the form with the desired id, but its values won't be set at all

what should I do?

Comment: because to applying viewstate you should create controls before Page_Load event, for example on Page_Init

Comment: but I saw examples that preserved the id and they were all in page_load

Comment: read about [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) if you can provide sample about you say it would be great

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

this article claims that it works and it acts in the page load

Comment: if you try it, you can see that after postback all inputs is clear. Because viewstate applying before Page_Load

Comment: or I could be wrong :-)

Comment: you not set id for controll that you Load, and also you not initialize `ControlTypes`

Comment: Yes. Grundy is right. Change your CreateControls method to set the control's Id. Control c = LoadControl(controlType, null); c.ID = controlId; panel.Controls.Add(c);

Comment: I am pretty sure this must be in the page_load event since it is using the viewstate to retrive the number of controls.also I do set the ids of the controls using `property.setvalue()` method

Comment: I also tried your way of setting the controls id, and I still get the same results

Comment: _I do set the ids of the controls using property.setvalue() method_ where you do this?

Comment: oops, I inserted my old code.Updated the code now